# Gulpfile.js - how to get .min.css, .css, and .css.map files on gulp.watch?

Tags: sass, gulp, minify

Ok, I've done lots of research on this, but on a drupal site, I have a zurb foundation theme and am super happy with it.  The only problem I'm having is when I customize the scss components.  I'm using gulp to compile it and it is recreating the css file fine.  However, I would like to get it to ALSO give me the min.css file and the css.map file, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I've tried many different iterations on the gulpfile.js but here is my latest.

It only produces the css file.

```
  var sassFiles = './themes/zurb_foundation/scss/**/*.scss',
    cssDest = './themes/zurb_foundation/css';

  gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))   
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))    
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: 'min.css' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./themes/zurb_foundation/css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))
 });

  gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(sassFiles, ['styles']);
 })
```

I've finally gotten it to produce the following error:

```
CssSyntaxError: /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/SITEFOLDER/ROOTDIR/themes/zurb_foundation/scss/foundation.scss:1:1: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the 
postcss-scss parser> 1 | // Foundation by ZURB
```

I guess at this point, my question would be how should I set-up my gulpfile to tackle the postcss-scss parsing?

Comment: Typically the sourcemaps calls surround the other plugins.  Look at a couple of examples of sourcemaps in action.  Are you saying you do not get any .min.css output to cssDest?

Comment: If you share the error message also maybe someone could help you about it.

Comment: Right, no .min.css at all.  Also, as I have it now, there are no sass.logErrors returning.  It gives the usual gulp.watch output in the console, but no errors.

Comment: I made it produce the edited error that I've included.

Comment: You’re using a CSS parser to try and handle a SASS file as per the error message

Comment: Yep.  Can you point me to any examples of setting up a gulpfile for this?

Comment: @user3558727 I have posted an answer with an example and a walk through of what it's doing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first of all we declare the necessary packages as `const` as these values shouldn't change their assignation.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
```

Then we write a gulp task called sass, in which we search for all files in the styles folder in an `.scss` format.

We check and log any errors, we create sourcemaps which allow the browser to map CSS generated by SASS back to the original source file (if you want to use your `.scss`/`.css` that way).

We then write your new `.css` files to the `public/styles` folder.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles'));
});
```

After which, we write a second gulp task called `minify-css`.

We look for all files in the `.css` format inside our styles folder.

First of all we auto prefix all our css properties. For example, if you have a css class where you have set:

```
user-select: none;
```

Autoprefixing will handle adding:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

After which we minify, concatenate and then name our new minified css file as `main.min.css` and then save it in the `public/styles` folder.

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function(){
    gulp.src(['./styles/*.css'])
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(rename("main.min.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles'));
});
```

We then write a task called `build`, so to call both the `sass` and `minify-css` tasks in chronological order by simply running `gulp build` in the terminal.

```
gulp.task('build', [‘sass’, ‘minify-css’]);
```